# What was the decision Madge Hardcastle took?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, second-best-exotic-marigold-hotel

I just saw and loved "The Second Best Exotic Marigold Hotel". Towards the end, Madge Hardcastle (Celia Imrie) is asked by her driver if she wants to turn left or right. Which man does she want to marry?  I believe she slowly smirks, and makes no decision. But after that I lost track of her story.  Whom did she choose?  Was it her driver (as I hope)? Was she on the back of one of the four scooters at the end?

Comment: Anyone have a reasonable idea for a tag? That's an awfully long title here and everything seems equally important.

Comment: "Best-Exotic-Marigold" maybe? Still pretty long.

Comment: Seems reasonable and it's not too long (it's only about being too long for the character limit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, she chose the driver and they were one of the couples on scooters at the end.

Comment: How come someone gave this a down-vote, if it's the correct answer?